# Update query not functioning

Tags: php, mysql, database, sql-update, crud

I'm trying to develop a small "To Do List" application. The data for the app is stored in a database, and it needs to perform all CRUD operations. As it is right now, Select, Insert, and Delete work just fine. I'm stuck on updating though. The index.php page is shown below:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require_once 'connect.php';

    if (isset($_POST['DeleteTask'])) {
        $sqldelete = "DELETE FROM Tasks WHERE dbTaskID = :bvTaskID";
        $stmtdelete = $db->prepare($sqldelete);
        $stmtdelete->bindValue(':bvTaskID', $_POST['taskID']);
        $stmtdelete->execute();
        echo "<div>Task successfully deleted</div>"; 
    }

    if (isset($_POST['theSubmit'])){
        echo '<p>New task added</p>';

        $formfield['ffTaskName'] = trim($_POST['taskName']);
        $formfield['ffTaskDue'] = trim($_POST['taskDue']);

        if(empty($formfield['ffTaskName'])){$errormsg .= "<p>Task field is empty.</p>";}
        if(empty($formfield['ffTaskDue'])){$errormsg .= "<p>Deadline field is empty.</p>";}

        if ($errormsg != "") {
                echo "<div class='error'><p>Please fill out all fields before submitting.</p>";
                echo $errormsg;
                echo "</div>";
        } else {
            try {
                $sqlinsert = 'INSERT INTO Tasks (dbTaskName, dbTaskDue, dbTaskDone)
                VALUES (:bvTaskName, :bvTaskDue, :bvTaskDone)';
                $stmtinsert = $db->prepare($sqlinsert);
                $stmtinsert->bindValue(':bvTaskName', $formfield['ffTaskName']);
                $stmtinsert->bindValue(':bvTaskDue', $formfield['ffTaskDue']);
                $stmtinsert->bindValue(':bvTaskDone', 0);
                $stmtinsert->execute();
                echo "<div><p>There are no errors.  Thank you.</p></div>";
            } catch(PDOException $e){
                echo 'ERROR!!!' .$e->getMessage();
                exit();
            }
        }   
    }

    $sqlselect = "SELECT * from Tasks";
    $result = $db->prepare($sqlselect);
    $result->execute();
?>


<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>To Do Application</title>
    </head>
    <body> 

        <h1><u>To-Do List</u></h1>
        <table border>
            <tr>
                <th>Task</th>
                <th>Deadline</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Complete</th>   
                <th>Edit</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
            <?php           
                while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
                    if ($row['dbTaskDone'] == 0) {
                        $status = "Unfinished";
                    } else {
                        $status = "Finished";
                    }
                    echo '<tr><td>' . $row['dbTaskName'] 
                    . '</td><td>' . $row['dbTaskDue']
                    . '</td><td>' . $status;

                    /*if ($status == "Unfinished"){
                        echo '</td><td>';
                        echo '<form action="'. $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '" method="post">';
                        echo '<input type="hidden" name="taskID" value"' . $row['dbTaskID'] . '">';
                        echo '<input type="submit" name="CompleteTask" value="Complete Task">';
                        echo '</form>';
                    }*/

                    echo '</td><td>';
                    echo '<form action="updateTask.php" method="post">';
                    echo '<input type="hidden" name="taskID" value="' . $row['dbTaskID'] . '">';
                    echo '<input type="submit" name="EditTask" id="EditTask" value="Edit Task">';
                    echo '</form></td><td>';

                    echo '<form action="'. $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '" method="post">';
                    echo '<input type="hidden" name="taskID" value="' . $row['dbTaskID'] . '">';
                    echo '<input type="submit" name="DeleteTask" value="Delete Task">';
                    echo '</td></tr>';
                }
            ?>
        </table>   
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" name="toDoForm">
            <fieldset><legend>New Task</legend>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Task</th>
                        <td><input type="text" name="taskName" id="taskName"
                        value="<?php echo $formfield['ffTaskName']; ?>"></td>
                    </tr><tr>
                        <th>Deadline</th>
                        <td><input type="text" name="taskDue" id="taskDue"
                        value="<?php echo $formfield['ffTaskDue']; ?>"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <input type="submit" name = "theSubmit" value="Add Task">
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Each record displays an "Edit" button that grabs the PK from the "Tasks" table and sends it to the updateTask.php page:

```
<?php 
    require_once 'connect.php';
    $errormsg = "";
    if (isset($_POST['EditTask']) ) {
        $formfield['ffTaskID'] = $_POST['taskID'];
        $sqlselect = "SELECT * FROM Tasks WHERE dbTaskId = :bvTaskID";
        $result = $db->prepare($sqlselect);
        $result->bindValue(':bvTaskID', $formfield['ffTaskID']);
        $result->execute();
        $row = $result->fetch(); 

        if( isset($_POST['theEdit']) )
        {   
            $formfield['ffTaskID'] = $_POST['taskID'];
            $formfield['ffTaskName'] = trim($_POST['taskName']);
            $formfield['ffTaskDue'] = trim($_POST['taskDue']);

            if(empty($formfield['ffTaskName'])){$errormsg .= "<p>Task field is empty.</p>";}
            if(empty($formfield['ffTaskDue'])){$errormsg .= "<p>Deadline field is empty.</p>";}

            if ($errormsg != "") {
                echo "<div class='error'><p>Please fill out all fields before submitting.</p>";
                echo $errormsg;
                echo "</div>";              
            } else {
                try
                {
                    $sqlUpdate = "UPDATE Tasks SET dbTaskName = :bvTaskName,
                                  dbTaskDue = :bvTaskDue
                                  WHERE dbTaskID = :bvTaskID";
                    $stmtUpdate = $db->prepare($sqlUpdate);
                    $stmtUpdate->bindvalue(':bvTaskName', $formfield['ffTaskName']);
                    $stmtUpdate->bindvalue(':bvTaskDue', $formfield['ffTaskDue']);
                    $stmtUpdate->bindvalue(':bvTaskID', $formfield['ffTaskID']);
                    $stmtUpdate->execute();
                }
                catch(PDOException $e)
                {
                    echo 'ERROR!!!' .$e->getMessage();
                    exit();
                }
            }
        }
    }   
?>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>To Do Application</title>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" name="editForm">
            <fieldset><legend>Edit Task</legend>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Task</th>
                        <td><input type="text" name="taskName" id="taskName"
                        value="<?php echo $row['dbTaskName'];?>" ></td>
                    </tr><tr>
                        <th>Deadline</th>
                        <td><input type="text" name="taskDue" id="taskDue"
                        value="<?php echo $row['dbTaskDue']; ?>"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Submit Changes</th>
                        <input type="hidden" name="taskID" value="<?php echo $_formfield['ffTaskID']; ?>">
                        <td><input type="submit" name="theEdit" value="Submit Changes">
                </table>

            </fieldset>
        </form> 
    </body>
</html>
```

The Name and Deadline fields populate appropriately based on the PK value passed from the last page. However, whenever I press the "Submit Changes" button, the update doesn't seem to execute. The page just refreshes and I see the table data remains unchanged in the database.

Comment: What debugging have you already done?

Comment: `if (isset($_POST['EditTask']) )` - I don't see any form element with the name `EditTask` so that if-statement will never evaluate as true.

Comment: There is but in wrong file i think  echo '<input type="submit" name="EditTask" id="EditTask" value="Edit Task">';

Comment: Sure, but you have to have it in the form you're posting.

Comment: @PatrickQ - Ah. Now I see. The issue is that one form contains `EditTask` (making the first if-statement true) but are missing the other required form fields the OP are looking for. Then, in the form in the second file, those form fields exists, but not `EditTask`, which means that it will _never_ reach the update code.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Nevermind.  That _is_ the problem.  On the second post that field isn't there.  Good spot.

Comment: @Jack This is why you should have separation of concerns.  One bit of code should handle just your display, and another should handle just your update, etc.

Comment: To be honest, the whole thing is just repurposed code I kept from school that worked just fine. There probably are better practices I could be following, but this is just what I know so far, heh.

I realized my mistake. To clarify for anyone else with this issue, in updateTask.php, I had the second if statement nested within the first one. So it was running the update query as the page loaded, with no change to the data. And the 'theEdit' button did nothing since since it required the previous if statement's condition to run.

Problem solved! Thanks for your help, Magnus and Patrick!

Comment: Could you add an answer to your own question and mark this as your solution? This will make sure this question does not remain open. And good to hear you found a solution to your problem!

Comment: @SaschaM78 You got it.

Comment: @SaschaM78 Scratch that. I jumped the gun. That didn't fix the issue.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson There seems to be more to it. See the edits to the original post.

Comment: @PatrickQ There's a bit more to it than I initially realized. Check the edits to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem!

There were several issues that I discovered.

1.) In updateTask.php, I had the second if-statement nested within the first one. So it was running the update query as the page loaded, with no change to the data. So the 'theEdit' button did nothing since since it required the previous if statement's condition to run.

2.) The formfield 'ffTaskID' at the bottom of the form on updateTask.php to be passed on the 'theEdit' button press was typed incorrectly.

> $_formfield

..should have been..

> $formfield

At this point, the update query functions properly.

3.) The issue with the 'Edit' buttons has been fixed. Though I honestly can't say for certain how it was fixed. It may have been linked with the first part of the problem. So when that was fixed, so was this.

Either way, all seems to be functioning as it should. Thanks again to everyone who commented and helped.